# Can I add a 0-100% number to my Sparkline on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to add a number that shows the percentage of this sparkline bar I created for my Google Sheets. Something that appears in the middle and says 50 when it's on 50%, 80 on 80% etc. Is this possible? The formula I have now :

```
=SPARKLINE(I10,{"charttype","bar";"color1", "orange";"max",I14})
```

This is how it looks now:

[image: How it looks now]

Comment: I have found something close to what you are looking for [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/percentage-progress-bar-in-google-sheets/#:~:text=Percentage%20Progress%20Bar%20Using%20the%20SPARKLINE%20Function%20in,progress%20bar%20in%20Google%20Sheets.%20%3Dsparkline%20%28%7BB3%2C600%7D%2C%20%7B%22charttype%22%2C%22bar%22%3B%22color1%22%2C%22green%22%3B%22color2%22%2C%22white%22%3B%22max%22%2C600%7D%29). Hope that it helps :) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdvv.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLdvv.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible to achieve directly where the sparkline is displayed. Best you can have is to have it under or next to it.